# Please find the exact equation for unknown polynomial using 50 points of (x,y)

Tags: polynomials

If we have $50$ points of known $(x,y)$ provided from a certain polynomial, ( note; this polynomial is unknown and we do not know it's degree). So is there any way to find the exact equation for this polynomial by using the value of $50$ points?( I am not looking here for the best fitting equation, I ask for the exact equation of the polynomial).

Thanks

Comment: You can just spam through the 50 points, or do you one a more convenient one?

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand your question. Could explain it again.

Comment: Related: [Find coefficients of a polynomial given several points on its plot](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21033) and [Find N degree polynomial from N+1 points](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/685472)

Answer (score 0):

Given that each value of x only has one y value, f(x) can be a degree 50 polynomial.

$f(x) = a_1x^{49} + a_2x^{48} + ... + a_{49}x + a_{50}$

For all the values of (x,y), substitute the values of x and y and solve.

However, in the case x has more than one y value, f(x) is not a polynomial.

---

At the OP's request, here is an elaboration.

Let us say there is a point (3,5)

We substitute this value in and we get $a_1*3^{49} + a_2*3^{48} + ... + a_{49}*3 + a_{50} = 5$

After 50 values, we can get an answer.

Comment: $49$ seems to be tha maximum degree (except if $a_{51}=0$), I guess.

Comment: Ok, what i want to say that the 50 points provided from certanin equation (let's say y= 10 - x^6 - 4x^2, but we do not know this equation). So is there any way to find the equatios by using the 50 points?

Comment: Hi, are you still with us and interested to answer this question?

Comment: This method generally will solve your problem, but it may give more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lagrangian polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) will interpolate your data points.

Then if your coordinates are exact and you compute the coefficients using exact arithmetic, the high degree terms will vanish by themselves.

If you coordinates are approximate, then you are in trouble as all coefficients will remain non-zero and you'll get a polynomial of the $49^{th}$ degree, as the method is highly unstable.

The [Neville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm) computation scheme (computing all coefficients, not just a value) should give you better insight as the intermediate polynomials should never exceed the actual degree and will tend to become equal.

A safer approach could be to compute fitting polynomials for increasing degrees and decide when the least-squares residue has dropped. It all depends on the quality of your data.

Make sure to know an upper bound on the degree !

Comment: Ok, what i want to say that the 50 points provided from certanin equation (let's say y= 10 - x^6 - 4x^2, but we do not know this equation). So is there any way to find the equatios by using the 50 points. I am looking to find the exact equation not the best fit equation.

Comment: Please spend some effort to read my answer. It directly addresses your request.

Comment: Thanks, but is this solution will give me the exact equation ( y= 10-x^6-4x^2)?

Comment: This is answered in the second and third paragraphs.

Comment: Neville, newten or Lagrang or any other interpolation method will be accurate on the known points ( 50 points) but will not be accurate in the interpolation or extrapolation area, so i am looking for away to estimate the exact equation ( y=10-x^6-4x^4).

Comment: This is answered in the first and second paragraphs. Lagrange is the minimum degree polynomial through given points, but the process is numerically unstable. Try it and see for yourself.